# Redirect without get-params

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I need to remove get params from url-string.There is code from .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On


        RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/
        RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://formaspravki.com? [R=301,L]

        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.formaspravki\.com
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://formaspravki.com/$1? [R=permanent,L]

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.forma-spravki\.com
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://formaspravki.com/$1? [R=permanent,L]

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^forma-spravki\.com
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://formaspravki.com/$1? [R=permanent,L]

        DefaultLanguage ru
        AddDefaultCharset windows-1251
        #php_value default_charset "cp1251"

        # Редиректы
        RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)(/?)$ index.php?cstart=$1? [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/page/([0-9]+)(/?)+$index.php?do=cat&category=$1&cstart=$2[L]
        RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ index.php?do=cat&category=$1 [L]

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/rss.xml$ engine/rss.php?do=cat&category=$1 [L]
        RewriteRule ^page,([0-9]+),([^\/]+).html$ index.php?do=static&page=$2&news_page=$1 [L]
        RewriteRule ^print:([^\/]+).html$ engine/print.php?do=static&page=$1 [L]

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^([^\/]+).html$ index.php?do=static&page=$1 [L]

        Redirect 301 /spravka_rabotodatelyu_o_beremennosti.html http://formaspravki.com/spravka-o-beremennosti.html
        Redirect 301 /spravka_o_beremennosti_obrazec.html http://formaspravki.com/spravka-o-beremennosti.html
```

Afer redirecting, in url string appears parametrs ?do=static&page='page name'.
When I add next code paramets disappering,but content in browser isn`t loading:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !="^do=static$"
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1? [L]
```

Adding '?' to the directive or deleting query string didnt help.

Comment: What rule exactly are trying to fix? There are some of them in your `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 0):

Try appending [`[QSD]` flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsd) to your url, for example:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://example.com [R=301,L,QSD]
```

Comment: Result is 500 error(afrer adding QSD).Maybe i can improve my code `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !="^do=static$"
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1? [L]`?Link is correct,but redirect is cyclic in browser.

Comment: You're effectively saying "If query string isn't exactly equal "do=static" then redirect all path as a parameter to example.com/$1". This will cycle indefinitely every request with empty query string.

Comment: QSD is applicable only for Apache 2.4 and later.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved!

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "^do=static&page=old-name$"
RewriteRule ^([^\/]+)$ new-link$1? [R=permanent,L]
```